# What is service worker in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

When creating a react app, service worker is invoked by default. Why service worker is used? What is the reason for default invoking?

Comment: all the answers below failed to mention why a service worker is added to React build BY DEFAULT. The answers are all talking about what is a service worker. But if 99% of the app isn't using it, why the default setting to be set to true.

Comment: @windmaomao can you clarify? Service workers in CRA improve page load perf by caching the FE assets in your browser.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You may not need a service worker for your application. If you are creating a project with create-react-app it is invoked by default

Service workers are well explained in this **[article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)**. To Summarise from it

> A `service worker` is a script that your browser runs in the
> background, separate from a web page, opening the door to features
> that don't need a web page or user interaction. Today, they already
> include features like `push notifications` and `background sync` and have
> `ability to intercept and handle network requests`, including
> `programmatically managing a cache of responses`.
>
> In the future, service workers might support other things like
> `periodic sync` or `geofencing`.

According to this **[PR to create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1728)**

> `Service workers` are introduced with create-react-app via
> `SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin`.
>
> Using a server worker with a cache-first strategy offers performance
> advantages, since the network is no longer a bottleneck for fulfilling
> navigation requests. It does mean, however, that developers (and
> users) will only see deployed updates on the "N+1"
> visit to a page, since previously cached resources are updated in the
> background.

The call to `register service worker` is enabled by default in new apps but you can always remove it and then you’re back to regular behaviour.

Comment: as for now generated reactjs app has sw code but comment states that register function is not called. So question is where to could I call it?

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov, you could call it at a top-level index.js file or similar.

Comment: @Siddhartha could you be kind enough to provide a concrete example, and maybe update the answer? I found this to be very useful but am missing those final details. Thanks.

Comment: is the service worker works fine when i deploy the app on nginx server ?

Answer (score 33):

**In simple and plain words, it’s a script that browser runs in the background and has whatsoever no relation with web pages or the DOM, and provide out of the box features. It also helps you cache your assets and other files so that when the user is offline or on slow network.**

*Some of these features are proxying network requests, push notifications and background sync. Service workers ensure that the user has a rich offline experience.*

You can think of the service worker as someone who sits between the client and server and all the requests that are made to the server pass through the service worker. Basically, a middle man. Since all the request pass through the service worker, it is capable to intercept these requests on the fly.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add 2 important considerations about Service Workers to take into account:

1. Service Workers require HTTPS. But to enable local testing, this restriction doesn't apply to `localhost`. This is for security reasons as a Service Worker acts like a *man in the middle* between the web application and the server.
2. With **Create React App** Service Worker is only enabled in the production environment, for example when running `npm run build`.

Service Worker is here to help developing a [Progressive Web App](https://web.dev/what-are-pwas/). A good resource about it in the context of Create React App can be found in their website [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/).